# How to click on an element with an unique attribute using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

The website has multiple turn off buttons and the only thing that differentiates between them is the `sales_area_uid` **257207**. How can I code this to click on the value of the uid?

HTML Source:

```
<input type="submit" class="button delete sales-area-status" name="submit_sales_area_status" data-sales-area-uid="275207" data-value="0" value="Turn Off">
```

Code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'/usr/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://izoneapps.zonalconnect.com/mobile_manager/login.php")

driver.implicitly_wait(7)

driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys('*****')
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys('*****')

driver.find_element_by_name("submit_login").click()

driver.get("https://izoneapps.zonalconnect.com/mobile_manager/ordering/")

driver.find_elements_by_xpath ("//div[@data-sales-area-uid=275207]").click()
```

Comment: Instead of the handcrafted HTML update the question with the text based actual HTML.

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: Ive updated post to show code and HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-sales-area-uid='275207']").click()
```

This should work for your problem

Answer (score 0):

The value of the *`data-sales-area-uid`* attribute seems dynamic. Now among the several <kbd>Turn Off</kbd> elements if the desired element is always assigned the same value of *`data-sales-area-uid`* i.e. ***275207*** then to click on the specific element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.button.delete.sales-area-status[data-sales-area-uid='275207']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='button delete sales-area-status' and @data-sales-area-uid='275207']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```